# Firebird 2.1 TIMESTAMP arithmetic and civil intervals

Tags: sql, timestamp, firebird, math, firebird2.1

My understanding is that, in keeping with Interbase v6, Firebird 2.5 does not support the SQL-92 `INTERVAL` keyword.  At least, so suggests [this reference](http://www.ibphoenix.com/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&page=ibp_60_sql_date_fs) and my repeated SQLCODE -104 errors trying to get `INTERVAL`s to work under Firebird's *isql(1)*.

How, then, do I account for the irregularities in our civil reckoning of time -- months aren't uniformly long, nor are days with savings time and leap adjustments, not to mention the year of confusion, etc. -- when performing `TIMESTAMP` arithmetic under Firebird 2.1?

How can I easily determine "one month earlier" or "one week later" than a given `TIMESTAMP`?  How about "one day later" or "two hours before"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the [DateAdd()](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-dateadd.html) and [DateDiff()](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-datediff.html) built-in functions.
Alternatively you may also use classic [date arithmetic](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq36/).

Comment: "Classic" date arith. doesn't let one work with civil intervals as an operand, but `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` seem spot on.  (I can't convince either method, however, to recognize the savings time change that happened in my time zone on 2009-03-08 -- too bad.)

Comment: @pilcrow: You can't get it to recognize DST changes, as that would assume the date / time to be local. The functions as-is seem to work with system time, which is a good thing as a database should always store timestamps in UTC.

Comment: @mghie, my system and my Firebird server are in local time.

Comment: @pilcrow: I guess most systems are, but that doesn't matter. The moment a database grows in usage to different time zones one wishes to have used UTC for all time stamps. The other possibility would be to store the offset to UTC with each time stamp, which still wouldn't allow for proper arithmetic, and there's no data type for it either. So UTC seems to be the only forward compatible way to store time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't implemented in Firebird, maybe you could do it through the technology calling your sql server, and get the resulting timestamp ? I know it can be quite easily done in Java or .Net

Comment: That's certainly a feasible alternative, Bishiboosh, but I'd rather work out the right SQL or server-side logic once, than several times with a variety of clients if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [functions](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-udf.html) of the external UDF fbudf.dll

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice external UDF named rFunc: http://rfunc.sourceforge.net/, it has nice Date functions like DaysBetween and IncDate(d, i1, i2, i3) and many more

Answer (score 0):

1. Subtract one day from timestamp date in a loop until month has changed.
2. Subtract one day from timestamp date in a loop until day has changed to SUNDAY.